# How to get fullcalendar month view showing event ranges that start before the current month?

Tags: 7, views, javascript

I'm doing some stuff with fullcalendar that is basically working, with ajax, to show a collection of events in a month-view calendar.  Everything is working, except for events that start outside the month on display.  That is, if I have an event that runs from February 15 to April 15, it will only show up in the February view -- it will *not* show up on either the March or April views.

I'm starting to hack around in the fullcalendar code to see how I might address this, but it's pretty slow going.  FWIW, I've tried flipping the "lazy fetching" option in the view's view's options, but without luck.  Has anybody run into this before; any insights about how to fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: Update: Sure enough, if I dig around and see what Views is up to, it's producing the code: `DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_data_field_event_date_range.field_event_date_range_value), '%Y-%m-%d') >= :field_data_field_event_date_range_field_event_date_range_value 

AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(field_data_field_event_date_range.field_event_date_range_value), '%Y-%m-%d') <= :field_data_field_event_date_range_field_event_date_range_value1`, which (I think) means it's only trying to show ranges that are fully inside the current month.  Any way around this?

Comment: I believe you are missing the "Start/End date range" setting in "Contextual filter: Date".

Comment: Thanks -- I tried that, but without much luck: I ended up with no dates showing at all (I may well have done it wrong).  I've spent some time digging around in the views and fullcalendar code, and it continues to look like one or the other of them is insisting on using `op_between`, which generates the code shown above.  I suppose I can hack that if I really want to (this is the only place I'm using views), but that's so wrong...